# How execute an void only after other void as been completed

Tags: java, android

How to make void "b" start only after void "a" has been completed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    a();
    b(); <- Only execute after "a();" has been finished (not at same time)
}

private void a(){
    //Code Here...
}

private void b(){
    //Code After Code "a" Finish...
}
```

Comment: Method are executed one after the other in java, just like you want. What make you think they don't?

Comment: call method a() inside b() or create a interface which notify that b() has been executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that **method**s a() and b() are in the same thread, they will not execute concurrently, but will execute sequentially, which sounds like what you want.

Note: you refer to these methods as 'void's.  That is incorrect.  They are methods, which happen to have a return type that is 'void', but which could just as easily be some other primitive or object return type.

Comment: Yes, but method "b" is executed after method "a" is executed and not finalized. (Assume there is a code inside method "a", and it takes some time to complete.)

Comment: Unless the code in method 'a' is specifically instructed to run on a separate thread (e.g., has a Runnable task), then it is guaranteed to finish before method 'b' is called.  If method 'a' never finishes, then method 'b' will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you won't use some asynchronous code in a(), b() won't run at the same time. If this is not the case, please post the asynchronous code too.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have two methods, void A and void B. Consider this:

```
public void a(){
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}

public void a(){
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}
```

(the example covers 100 repetitions for it to be easy to see). If you look closely, "b" will print when "a" is finished. Java executes in order. If you sleep for 10 seconds in A, and everything happens on the same thread, B will execute after the 10 seconds have elapsed.

If you use the for-loops above and change it to a much higher amount(to make sure it takes a while), you still see B does NEVER execute until A is finished. This does not apply if a contains an async task or a new thread, as that runs on a second thread aside the first thread. But that is the only exception: In all other cases where the methods are executed on the same thread and everything inside the methods are on the same thread, A will finish before B starts

---

But you can of course do this:

```
...
a();
...

public void a(){
   ...
    b();
}

public void b(){
    ...
}
```

but it is the same as calling:

```
....
a();
b();
....
```